# how to unset/remove a protected property

Tags: php

I have a Product object/class as follows:

```
class Product
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\MinLength( limit=3, message=" Product Name should have at least {{ limit }} characters.")
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100 , nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=350)
     */
    protected $description;


    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $code;


    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Min(limit = "0", message = "negative number is invalid")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid number.")
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Min(limit = "0", message = "negative number is invalid")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid number.")
     * @ORM\Column(name="height", type="float")
     */
    protected $height;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Min(limit = "0", message = "negative number is invalid")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid number.")
     * @ORM\Column(name="width", type="float")
     */
    protected $width;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Min(limit = "0", message = "negative number is invalid")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid number.")
     * @ORM\Column(name="length", type="float")
     */
    protected $length;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Min(limit = "0", message = "negative number is invalid")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid number.")
     * @ORM\Column(name="weight", type="float" )
     */
    protected $weight;

    /**
     * @Accessor(getter="getShopRef")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\Shop", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE" , nullable=false)
     */
    protected $shop;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductAttribute", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    protected $attributes;

}
```

and so I have a Product object and I wanted to remove all the attributes of that product, so I did:

```
unset(product->attributes)
```

however it complained that the attributes can't be accessed. How is it possible to set the attributes of the Product to be nil?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you realize that unsetting won't affect persisted data?

Comment: What zerkms said. You are better of just instantiating a new object rather than trying to "clean" an existing object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition a protected property can only be accessed from within an instance of the class it is defined in or a descendant.

This is why one would opt choose to make a property protected vs. public, to make it unavailable for changing outside of instances of the class.

To unset it would have to be done from within the class i.e.

```
  public function removeAttributes(){
      unset($this->attributes);
  }
```

Comment: I would also add a loop/condition `property_exists($this, $property)` to make sure it exists.

Comment: Not necessary, in PHP unsetting a non-existent property or variable is not an error.  https://3v4l.org/0YuhC

Answer (score 5):

Your could use reflection to set a private/protected property to `null`.

http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setvalue.php

```
class Foo {
    public static $staticProperty;

    public $property;
    protected $privateProperty;
}

$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('Foo');

$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('privateProperty');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
$reflectionProperty->setValue($foo, null);
```

Comment: What if the property is type-hinted and not nullable?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd have to make a public function for it:

```
class product{
    // Include everything from above

    public function unset_attributes(){
        unset($this->attributes);
    }
}
```

More on protected variables within objects can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) instead of `unset` like this:

```php
$this->channels = ['value_1', 'value_2'];

$this->channels = array_values(array_diff($this->channels, array('value_1')));
```